# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred. Microsoft visual studio community 2017

Tags: c#, xaml

Please can someone be of help. I encountered this exception below, while trying to compile an XAML code.

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
> HResult=0x80131501
> Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '28' and line position '22'.
> Source=PresentationFramework
> StackTrace:
> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
> at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
> at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
> at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
> at XAMLImage.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in c:\users\mypc\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XAMLImage\XAMLImage\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
>
> Inner Exception 1:
> IOException: Cannot locate resource 'images/tahoe_01.jpg'.

The exception occurred at "InitializeComponent()" of the c# partial class of the code behind. Below is the c# partial class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace XAMLImage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="XAMLImage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLImage"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="604">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height = "1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height = "1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width = "200" VerticalAlignment = "Top" Margin = "30"/>
            <Image Width = "200" Source = "Images\flow5.gif" 
            VerticalAlignment = "Top" Margin = "30" Opacity = "0.5"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row = "1">
            <Ellipse Height = "100" 
            Width = "200" 
            HorizontalAlignment = "Center" 
            Margin = "30">

                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource = "Images\bubble.png" />
                </Ellipse.Fill>

            </Ellipse>



        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is a blue squiggly line under the Source URL of the Image and ImageSource URL of the ImageBrush elements. I hover my mouse over them, and intellisense says "could not find file 'c:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\images%5Cmyfilename.gif'"(one of the files is a gif, and the other is a png). I thought these was an unsual path for the file to be located, but I went on and created the URLs on that path, but expection, still throwing.

Please can someone be of help. Am using Microsoft visual studio community 2017

Cheers

Comment: If you write ImageSource = "Images\tahoe_01.jpg" then the image should be in a folder called Images under your solution. Is there one such folder?

Comment: @Mishka Thanks for your reply. I edited my question after your comment. The path is Images\flow5.gif. Yes. I added it to my solution, still exception throwing. I added it to my project(and I can see the images, in the XAML designer), still exception throwing.

Comment: When you right click your images under your solution, and click to see Properties, what is the 'Build Action' of the images? and what is the 'Copy to Output Directory' value?

Comment: @Mishka. When I click on the images folder, and click to see properties, I don't see any of that. The images folder property pane is more or less blank. Shows only field(name), with value images

Comment: ??? I meant if you check the properties of the files of the images under the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio..

Comment: @Mishka. Just did that. Shows these fields: name(value = filename), date created, date modified, filepath(value = filepath), file size, read-only(value = false)

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in Visual Studio? these sound like windows properties..

Comment: @Mishka. Yea. I expanded the images folder, under the solution explorer, right clicked on an image file, clicked on properties

Comment: Can you please capture screen of your Solution Explorer with Properties open with your image properties and the images in the file tree?

Comment: @Mishka. Ok I will do that mate

Comment: @Mishka. Sorry for the delay mate. Trying to figure out how to share a photo via a link. Here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pl9erujn7gczac/Screenshot%20%281%29.png?dl=0

Comment: sorry for the delay also, link is dead btw, use imgur.

Comment: @Mishka. My bad. Thanks for your reply. Here's a new link https://www.dropbox.com/s/rs6xtlw8tvw37lg/Screenshot%20%283%29.png?dl=0

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. You see, the image is indeed in the solution, but not as part of your project. There is no copying of the image when compiling, there is no embedding of the image inside the compiled exe/dll. You need the images folder to be part of the project, or to have a Post Build event on your project that will also copy those images to the output folder after compiling.

Comment: @Mishka. I've been trying to add the images folder from my IDE, to my project, but I can't. When I right click the project, under the solution explorer, click add, click existing item, locate the existing images folder, it's always empty, and unable to add to the project. Am only able to add it to my project, from windows explorer. Still throwing exceptions. Please can you tell me how I should go about doing the things you said in your last answer. Cheers

Comment: You can copy paste the images with their folder under your project in regular windows file explorer(outside Visual Studio).
Then, in Visual Studio, go to solution explorer, upper bar there an icon button for 'Show All Files'. After clicking, you should see the folder, but with low opacity. Right click on it and then 'Include In Project'.
That will do it.

Comment: @Mishka. Cheers mate. God bless you. All done

Comment: @Mishka https://www.dropbox.com/s/e4ird46hd01kjmz/Screenshot%20%284%29.png?dl=0

Comment: So... I guess it works?

Comment: @Mishka Yes mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a good person in these community, I managed to solve the problem. You need the images folder to be part of the project. The images folder needs to be in the same folder as the code files. These you can achieve by copying and pasting the images folder into the same folder as the code files, in windows file explorer. After these I was able to see the images on my designer. But the project still doesn't know about the images(at least during compile/run time). For the project to know about the images folder, it needs to be included into the project. These you can achieve by, in Visual Studio, go to solution explorer, upper bar there's an icon button for 'Show All Files'. After clicking, you should see the folder, but with low opacity. Right click on it and then 'Include In Project'.